# AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification not called after audio is done playing

Tags: ios, xcode

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I can't detect when my sound is done playing.  I can get it working for video no problem.  I've been searching for the past two hours and none of the solutions I've come across seem to work.

The sound plays fine.  I just need to know when it finishes playing.

.h

```
@interface soundController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

}

- (IBAction) soundButtonClicked;
- (void) soundDidStop:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

.m

```
- (IBAction) soundButtonClicked {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/my_sound.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];  
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                          selector:@selector(soundDidStop:)
                          name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                          object:audioPlayer];
    [audioPlayer play];

}


- (void) soundDidStop:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@""
                          message:@"sound stopped"
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];


}
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009532-CH1-SW38) is a notification available to AVPlayerItem, which is not what you're using in your code up there.

You're using [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/), a totally different object with a totally different interface.

And in your case, you can use the AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol.  The delegate method you want to catch is [`audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAudioPlayerDelegate/audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply.  I did try that but I got a warning "'AVAudioPlayer' may not respond to 'currentItem'".  I tried running anyway to see if it would work, but unfortunately now I get a SIGABRT. :\

Comment: Ahhh, I just realized that you're using AVAudioPlayer and not AVPlayer, which is what the notifications actually work with. But even better, with AVAudioPlayer, you have delegate methods available that you can use.

Comment: Thanks!! That did the trick!  I guess its apparent that I have no idea what I'm doing. :P  You're a life saver!